# How to clear cookies using python 2.6.x cookielib

Tags: python, cookies

It seems my previous description was not clear, so rewriting it.

Using python urllib2, I am automating fileupload task in my webapp. And am using Cookielib to store session information, and also I could able to successfully automate the fileupload task. Problem is, when I change the login credentials and did not supply those or supply wrong login credentials to automated python script, it still processing fileupload successfully. In this case, it should actually fail.

All I want is, how to clear the cookielib generated cookies.

Below is the code snippet....

```
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
cookies.clear_session_cookies()
#cookies.clear() tried this as well
opener = urllib2.build_opener(SmartRedirectHandler,HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies),MultipartPostHandler)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)
login_req = urllib2.Request(login_url, login_params)
res = urllib2.urlopen(login_req)
#after login, do fileupload
fileupload_req = urllib2.Request(fileupload_url, params)
response = urllib2.urlopen(import_req)
```

I tried using clear() and clear_session_cookies() but still cookies are not cleared.

Comment: Sorry for bad description, I want to clear the cookies so that urllib2 request can take new login credentials to login into the application. rite now I am not able to clear the cookies

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the opener that you have built, otherwise it will just keep using the default

Comment: As you said, I used opener to make a request for both login and fileupload request, it is still successfull with wrong credentials. Old cookies are not getting cleared, and new credentials are not taken.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on cookies, I am restricting page access based response headers. Now, I could able to stop the file upload process when wrong credentials supplied. Thanks guys.